# Checkbox field not visible in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor

I am working in asp.net. Trying to display data in gridview retrieved from a web service. I want five fields in gridview, one checkbox field and other four are values from service i.e.

```
CheckboxField,FirstName,LastName,OffenseName,FineAmount
```

1 ) Following is gridview code, that i just dragged and dropped into page

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
      <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCFF33" />
</asp:GridView>
```

2 ) Following is my method that i call, to create fields in a DataTable, which i will bind to gridview later.

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(CheckBox)); // i think problem is here
table.Columns.Add("FirstName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("LastName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("OffenseName", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("FineAmount", typeof(string));
```

3) Following is code to that populates the data table, with data

```
for (int i = 0; i < noOfContacts; i++)
{
        object[] rowVals = new object[5];        
       rowVals[0] = giveCheckBox(i);             // this method is declared below, which gives me a checkbox with unique id
       rowVals[1] = listOfContacts[i].FirstName;
       rowVals[2] = listOfContacts[i].LastName;
       rowVals[3] = listOfCharges[j].GHQOffenseId;
       rowVals[4] = listOfCharges[j].GHQFineAmount;
       table.Rows.Add(rowVals);
}
            GridView1.DataSource = table;
            GridView1.DataBind();
```

4) This is method that gives me a checkbox, with unique id

```
public CheckBox giveCheckBox(int i)
    {
        CheckBox chk = new CheckBox();
        chk.ID = "chk_" + i;
        chk.Text = "Pay";
        return chk;
    }
```

**Problem** is that when i run the program, it only display four fields but not first checkbox field. I want to dispay that must.
**But** if i add checkbox field in designing view, (click arrow on gridview, click Add New Fields), then it throws exception at binding line i.e.

```
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Please guide me how to make checkbox field visible.

Answer (score 0):

Instead adding the checkbox to your table(which is wrong anyway) add a template field to the gridview as below. Also specify AutoGenerateColumns=true. Then remove all the code in your codebehind which tries to add checkbox column to the table and gridview.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxSelect" runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCFF33" />
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: I am getting following error now

Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not have a public property named 'TemplateField'
Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not have a public property named 'ItemTemplate'
Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' does not have a public property named 'Checkbox'

Comment: sorry mistake, templatecolumn should be under <Columns>. edited the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can insert all your fields in design like code below :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCFF33" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chk_box" />
               </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

            <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OffenseName" HeaderText="OffenseName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FineAmount" HeaderText="FineAmount" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

and for the code behind:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable();

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
            DataRow dr = table.NewRow();
            dr["FirstName"] = "Ahmed";
            dr["LastName"] = "Ahmed";
            dr["OffenseName"] = "Ahmed";
            dr["FineAmount"] = "Ahmed";
            table.Rows.Add(dr);
}

GridView1.DataSource = table;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're right the problem lies exactly in that code snippet. Replace the following line

```
table.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(CheckBox));
```

with this one

```
table.Columns.Add("Select", typeof(bool));
```